# is it possible to get a remote for 99 ml430 mercedes

Tags: mercedes-benz, ignition-key, keyless-entry

i have a 99 ml430 mercedes recently purchased, only 1 key avail the valet key, after talking to many locksmiths and dealers in area [richmond,va]unable to get a remote for vehicle, found a new remote online unprogrammed and key not cut is it possible to get this done [remote programmed/key cut] anywhere

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

Its not that it can't be done, the problem with these are the aftermarket remotes never work at all. Even with refurbished originals sometimes the remote portion will not add correctly. This causes us who are able to do it to just turn down these jobs since its not always worth wasted time and upset customers. if we decide to take them it will not be as cheap as what someone may expect because of the work and risk involved, also ending up with an upset customer.

I am also in Richmond, VA and I do these sometimes but it depends on where and how my schedule is looking for the next few days. I only know of one other smith in the area that does them as well. I would post our company info but I am not sure what the policies are on this website about such things.

As far as the dealer goes I remember seeing an internal memo that those type of keys (ml flip keys) where discontinued and only the standard valet style would be issued.

Comment: Thanks for your ans i some how must have missed you in my search  ok i understand your position  in that case can you give me the other smith's name i would like to see if i have one of the successful attempts

Comment: Talked to the other guy earlier today, he doesn't do them at all anymore but maybe I will give it a shot for you. Search "Keyworks Richmond VA" and send me a text. I have a few good aftermarket tools for the job and also carry benz dealer tool & software. Can't guarantee the remote part will work tho.